# Adobe Air Flex mobile sample project generator

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe, code-generation

I remember there was an application written on Air, that could generate mobile sample project on Air based on the list of features (multi touch, sqlite, sound, mic, etc.) that a user choosed.
It was very helpfull to understand base features of Air and to get working example for them.

What is the name of this app?

Answer (score 2):

Not if you talk about the Tour de Flex, but I leave the link as it has good examples

[Go to Tour de Flex](http://flex.apache.org/tourdeflex/index.html)

Regars.

Comment: Thanks, matilu. Tour De Flex is good but that app could generate project without need of downloading, importing. Something like Maven Archetypes or git seeds.

Comment: Ahh ok, I do not know but if you read something or you notice abut. regars.